# How to match a lookup table by detecing possibly multiple substrings as in matching "US|USA|United States" with `abc,United States,xzy` in R?

Tags: r, regex, lookup

I am not very sure about the terminology in the question title but I have a data frame containing non-structured addresses of institutions and I would like to extract their countries with a lookup table with multiple possible matches.

the addresses might look like:

```
address
xxx US
xxx USA yy
xxx United States yy
xxx UK
xxx United Kingdom yy
```

Note that not necessarily the country comes at the end of the string.

The pipeline would be matching and extracting whatever might be a country name (from a list of around 20 countries) and return a *clean* country name for each country.

```r
(df <- tribble(
    ~address,                 ~clean_country,
    "xxx US",                 "United States",
    "xxx, USA yy",            "United States",
    "xxx United States, yy",  "United States",
    "xxx UK",                 "United Kingdom",
    "xxx United Kingdom yy",  "United Kingdom",
    "xxx zz yy",              NA_character_,
))
```

I am thinking of creating a lookup table as a data.frame with two columns:

```r
(lookup <- tribble(
    ~country,          ~matches,
    "United States",   "US|USA|United States",
    "United Kingdom",  "UK|United Kingdom"
))
```

and then checking with **regex** if any of the *vertical bar* separed `matches` can be found in the
`df$address` column, then appending the column `country` as `clean_country` in `df`.

Of course, I am interested in solutions following other strategies. The more (memory) efficient because the data set is relatively big.

Comment: Can there be more than one country to detect per each string value?

Comment: each address is only one address, but words like "Georgia" are indeed ambiguous (the state in USA and the country in Europe). But for simplicity, we can assume ambiguity won't be a big deal. I will probably rank the countries in the lookup table and get the first that matches by expecting that the first match is the more likely to be the correct guess.

Comment: Speaking about efficiency, `US|USA|United States` is not an efficient way to write a regex because you are most likely to be using an NFA regex engine (as in stringr regex functions). You must make sure each alternative does not match at the same location, so `U(?:SA?|nited States)` is a much more efficient regex. And using word boundaries will make it even more precise, `"\\bU(?:nited States|SA?)\\b"`.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, these tips might come in handy with the whole set (and maybe even to avoid ambiguous matches)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the lookup table approach you can extract the country name from `address` using `str_extract` and replace it with country name in the loookup table.

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(str_extract(df$address, str_c(lookup$matches, collapse = '|')), 
                setNames(lookup$country, lookup$matches))

#[1] "United States"  "United States"  "United States" 
#[4] "United Kingdom" "United Kingdom" NA
```